# Why am I getting a string to float error in my code?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

i am getting a "could not convert string to float: '\ufeffage'" error and I don't know why

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
import os;

path = pd.read_csv('car.csv')

path.replace(",",".")

dataset=np.loadtxt("car.csv", delimiter=",")
x=dataset[:,0:5]
y=dataset[:,5]
y=np.reshape(y, (-1,1))
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
print(scaler.fit(x))
print(scaler.fit(y))
xscale=scaler.transform(x)
yscale=scaler.transform(y)
```

this last part is where the error occurs

Comment: Because your data contains strings as the error suggests, and `MinMaxScaler` only accepts numerical values

Comment: the data set is only numbers. will it accept decimals and 0?

Comment: The error is telling you that the data contains the string `'\ufeffage'" `

Comment: this is the data I am using. (https://github.com/MGCodesandStats/datasets/edit/master/cars.csv) I have tried it with and with out the heading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are reading contains byte order mark and column names. Pandas `read_csv` automatically takes care of this, but `np.loadtext` doesn't. Changing the first three lines of the script to this should help:

```
dataset=pd.read_csv('car.csv').values
```